# Error capture of perl script in shell

Tags: perl, shell

I am trying to captuer the actual error of the perl script if it fails. And its not stopping and the next script is getting triggered.

**UPDATED**
Python scripts are running fine only having problem with the perl script

```
if ! perl test.pl arg2 arg1 ;   
        then
        echo "Error running test.pl in Preparing data for algorithm; rest of process stopped." >&2 >>$LOG_PATH/Perl_RUN_$TRACK_TIME

    elif ! python themes.py;
        then
        echo "Error running themes.py rest of process stopped." >&2 >>$LOG_PATH/Python_RUN_$feed_name'_'$TRACK_TIME 

    elif ! python $SCRIPT_PATH/pre_survey_dt.py;
        then
        echo "Error running pre_survey_dt.py rest of process stopped." >&2 >>$LOG_PATH/Python_RUN_$TRACK_TIME
fi
```

Please advice what I am missing here.

Comment: What's the question here? Nothing in that snippet is going to cause your script to exit. If you want the script to do that you need to tell it to `exit`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ! perl test.pl arg2 arg1; then
    echo "test.pl failed with error code $?" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Use `return` instead of `exit`:

- to return from a shell function.
- to exit from a shell script that has been sourced.